# Getting data from JSON (i think)

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, webhooks

I hope someone here can help me with this as i am at a loose end. I have a little experience with programming (variables, etc) but not much at all with Javascript, JSON and many others.
Unfortunalty i cannot fully describe what im doing as it invloves sensitive info but i will try my best:
My plan is to collect data from a webhook and enter it into a google sheet which can then be seen by myself and my colleagues (and it needs to be as 'real-time' as possible, hence using webhooks instead of API - i think)

Ive been using google apps script and javascript

At the moment i just want to be able to collect the data from 1 variable, once i know how to do that i can hopefully figure out how to get the rest of the data that i need from the other variables - but there is another problem, the JSON data seems to come in 2 different formats which to be perfectly honest i confusing the **** out of me, so if anyone can could you please explain as best you can what i need to do.

I have looked at w3 schools and a number of other sites and forums (of which this one seemed to make the most sense hence me asking on here) but most of it has fryed my brain.

anyway here is what i need : 
I would like to get the data from "title" - in this example "Order #301428\"
here is part of the webhook i have received - the data has made it to the spreadsheet but it is in one massive string which is no good to me, i need to be able to just grab the data i need.

also could someone please tell me how to enter the data i need in a google sheet

Thank you very much in advance for any help

here is the 1st format that i have recieved (not complete as sensitive data) :

```
{"parameter":{},"postData":{"contents":"{\"id\":12374453,\"title\":\"Order #301428\",\"created_at\":\"2020-04-28T23:43:13.000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2020-04-30T10:52:27.000Z\",\"customer_id\":10960996,\"user_id\":14426,\"status\":4,\"scheduled_at\":\"2020-04-30T10:00:00.000Z\",\"merchant_id\":149,\"extras\":{\"previous_task_distance\":null,\"distance_to_team\":null},\"
```

here is the 2nd format :

```
{"contextPath":"","parameters":{},"contentLength":23356,"parameter":{},"queryString":"","postData":{"contents":"{\"id\":12425150,\"title\":\"Order #354554\",\"created_at\":\"2020-04-30T09:14:01.000Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2020-04-30T10:43:11.000Z\",\"customer_id\":11003352,\"user_id\":14894,\"status\":4,\"scheduled_at\":\"2020-04-30T11:00:00.000Z\",\"merchant_id\":149,\"extras\":{\"previous_task_distance\":null,\"distance_to_team\"
```

thank you again

Thank you all for your help - i've looked through numerous tutorials and other information but no matter what i do i cant get it to work and i honestly have no idea what im doing wrong - the thing that is really getting me is i can get the long string of data to show up in google sheets so i know ive got the connection there right - but when i follow any of the advice regarding JSON.parse, Javascript objects, JSON.stringify or anything else it just doesnt work - heres my code (my latest test)

```
var data = JSON.parse(e);
var orderno = data.postData.contents[1];

sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1,1,1).setValue([orderno]);
```

for some reason i cant enter all of my code

Comment: Both are JSON, you need to convert the JSON string into an object, using JSON.parse(). It appears there's a second part which is also a string, you'll need to use the same method there as well. You can then access the JSON using properties. You may find this useful: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-json-in-javascript

Comment: Go through a Javascript tutorial. Otherwise, you will just find yourself completely lost again. A few hours of learning some beginner javascript will go a long way for you. JSON.parse and Javascript Objects are where you will find the info you need.

Comment: Also check out the [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) method of a Spreadsheet Range, as if you want to set values to more than just one cell you need to fomat your array correctly and use this method to put it into the sheet.

Comment: thank you for the help but i honestly cannot figure out how to make this work - no matter what i try it doesnt work - ive tried numerous tutorials and forums and asked for advice in many places but nothing works - the really irritating thing is that it looks like it should work but doesnt and i just cannot figure out why - but anyway, thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Take the json and parse it into an object:

```
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp
```

You should then be able to access the attributes like so:

obj.postData

PostData appears to be another json string embedded in the first json, so you will need to parse that as well.